# FragmentContainerView in ViewHolder - which is the appropriate FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragment-manager

I am including a fragment in a row for a `RecyclerView` - I know it is not the most recommended thing to do, but it is not used much and I would like it as a `Fragment` as we are using it multiple places.

I have added this in the view for the `ViewHolder`:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/productRecommendationSectionFragment"
    android:name="dk.xxx.ui.sections.productRecommendation.ProductRecommendationSectionFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:tag="ProductRecommendationSectionFragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It loads fine as expected but the question is then how to access the correct FragmentManager to configure the fragment?

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView) states that it `".. add the Fragment to the appropriate FragmentManager"` and you should be able to access it by the tag.

But it does not seems to be either the contraining Fragment´ `Fragment.fragmentManager` or `Fragment.childFragmentManager`, nor the `Activity.fragmentManager`. (Tested by a delegate to Containing Fragment)

Which could it then be?

One clue could be that in the ViewHolder calling `binding.root.findFragment<ContainingFragment>()` resulting in `IllegalStateException`:

> "View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView...
> app:id/productRecommendationSectionFragment} does not have a Fragment
> set"

**Edit:**

I have tried those fragment managers from the containing fragment through a delegate.

```
activity!!.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ProductRecommendationSectionFragment") // null
childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ProductRecommendationSectionFragment") // null
fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ProductRecommendationSectionFragment") // null
```

Comment: You said that it doesn't seem to be any of the fragment managers you've tried. Can you include the code you have tried and what it resulted in?

Comment: @HenryTwist I have now added the cases I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging in `FragmentContainerView` itself, I have hopefully found all the cases of the `FragmentManager` used whilst adding a fragment via the `android:name` attribute.

- Fragments in the activity view hierarchy (from `Activity.setContentView(Int)`): `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`
- Fragments in another fragments hierarchy (from `Fragment.onCreateView(...))`: `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager`
- Fragments in a `RecyclerView` row, where the `RecyclerView` is **either** in a `Fragment` or an `Activity`: `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Now the first two are well documented and not of interest here, but I found the third case to be surprising, especially as it doesn't seem to make a difference what the `RecyclerView` has been inflated into. If I had to take a guess of why this is, it would probably be in `onCreateViewHolder`.When you inflate your row you pass `false` into the inflate function's `attachToRoot`, so as the `FragmentContainerView` is not attached to a parent when it is initialised, it has to use the highest level fragment manager - from the activity. However this is just speculation.

Regardless, in answer to your question - it is definitely the activities fragment manager.

---

You also said that you have tried using all the fragment managers anyway and they all couldn't find your fragment, but I wasn't able to replicate this problem. I managed to find my fragment in the `RecyclerView` just fine so I would expect there's something else going on that we can't find from the code you've shown, in theory it works.

Comment: I then just uncommented that line to test again with `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` and now it is working! I don't know how I have missed that this case was working - thanks for the investigation!